# Как на cmake сгенерировать решение Visual Studio с 2-мя платформами x86 и x64 в одном решении?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Есть исходный код, из него должно собираться две программы. Программ А определяет разрядность системы и запускает соотв. версию программы Б (x86/x64). Как мне написать CMakeList.txt, чтобы он собрал мне одно решение Visual Studio, которое бы включала 2 проекта: проект А и проект Б сразу с настройками под 2 платформы (x86|x64)?

Answer (score -1):

Cmake не может это сделать, генерируйте 2 проекта через ключи

```
cmake .. /*другие флаги*/ -A Win32
cmake .. /*другие флаги*/ -A x64
```

Или укажите параметры для каждого проекта CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM.html

```
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x86
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64
```

Добавьте 2 версии чтобы они собирались отдельно в одном солюшене. Соберите 2 версии и назовите их соответсвенно. Одну *_x86 другую *_64. В зависимости от системы запускайте необходимую.

Comment: Это понятно. А есть какие-нибудь трюки, чтоб сделать как в вопросе?

Comment: @IvanSh. Я же вам ответил, соберите 2 версии и назовите их соответсвенно. Одну *_x86 другую *_64. В зависимости от системы запускайте необходимую

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, как вы написали я и сам могу сделать. Мне нужно, чтобы две платформы были в одном решении VS, а не отдельно. Это нужно для дальнейшего написания кода и отладки. Если стандартно нельзя, есть ли какие-нибудь трюки?

Comment: @IvanSh. Upd answer

Comment: вот это "Добавьте 2 версии чтобы они собирались отдельно в одном солюшене" каким образом в одно решение сделать?

Comment: @ в основной проект заинклюдте и все а варами платформу выберете на выхлопу будет у вас два виндовых ехе . Читайте мат часть по cmake

Comment: Я не об этом. Ладно, всё ясно.